# Discord.py Clearing Bots Messages

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Does Anyone Know How I Can Clear/Purge Just Bots Messages, I Have Made A Purge Command But I Dont Know How To Only Delete Messages Sent By A Bot! Any Help Would Be Appreciated!

Comment: Can you share your code with us? [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Just figured out, purging messages also deletes messages sent by a bot.

Comment: when bot creates message then it get `message_id` which it can keep on list and later it can use it to delete theses messages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try to show what you have tried and what problems you are facing next time, this makes it easier to answer questions.

To solve your problem, you can use `Channel.history`. Unfortunately, you will have to purge messages manually rather than with `channel.purge`.

This code should work for you:

```
@client.command()
async def purge(ctx, limit : int):
  num = 0
  async for m in ctx.channel.history():
    if m.author == client.user:
      await m.delete()
      num += 1
      if num == limit:
        break
```